# Как создать пост на странице с помощью POST запроса?

Tags: reactjs, post, request, fetch

Отправляю POST запрос, но сам пост не отрисовался на странице. В консоли показывает, что новый элемент добавляется.

Подскажите, в чем ошибка?

```
const Posts = ({ getResourse }) => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [userId, setUserID] = useState("");
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [body, setBody] = useState("");

  const newPosts = (post) => {
    const body = post.body;
    const title = post.title;
    const id = post.id;

    return (
      <Col span={8} key={id + title}>
        <p>{id}</p>
        <p>{title}</p>
        <p>{body}</p>
      </Col>
    );
  };

  const fetchFunct = () => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        title: title,
        body: body,
        userId: userId,
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((res) => {
        posts.push(res);
        
        setPosts(posts);
      });
  };
  const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    fetchFunct();
    console.log(posts);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getResourse("posts")
      .then((array) => {
        console.log(array);
        setPosts(array);
      })
      .catch();
  }, []);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    
  }, [])


  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
          <div>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="userId"
              value={userId}
              onChange={(e) => setUserID(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="title"
              value={title}
              onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="body"
              value={body}
              onChange={(e) => setBody(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
          <button type="submit"> submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <Row justify="center">{posts.map((user) => newPosts(user))}</Row>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
const getResourse = async (query) => {
   const res = await fetch(https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/${query});
   const result = await res.json();
   return result;
 };
```

Comment: зачем вы удалили этот вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1241445/191482   с уже написанным ответом?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для того, чтобы reactjs понял, что состояние изменилось, нужно заменить

> posts.push(res);
>
> setPosts(posts);

на это

```
setPosts([...posts, res]);
```

Comment: а подскажите еще, пожалуйста, как лучше установить уникальный ключ для каждого нового поста? сейчас у меня он одинаковый получается для новых

Comment: `id: Date.now()`