# React useState хук не обновляет элементы в map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, react-hook

У меня есть state tags:

```
const [tags, setTags] = useState(['hello', 'ok', 'good']);
```

Есть вывод:

```
{tags.map((tag, index) => {
      return <span className="tag-item" onClick={removeTag} data-key={index} key={index}><i className="far fa-times"></i> {tag}</span>
})}
```

И функция-обработчик, которую я вызываю из элементов внутри:

```
function removeTag(e){
    tags.splice($(e.target).attr('data-key'), 1);
    setTags(tags);
}
```

При клике на элемент - он убирается. Все работает, я проверял в консоли. Кроме обновления страницы. Список тегов совсем не меняется хотя сам стейт я обновил. Почему так и как это исправить?

Comment: `setTags` должен получить _новый_ массив

Comment: @nörbörnën верно, уже нашел)

Comment: значит вопрос можно удалить

Comment: @nörbörnën лучше напишите ответ. Я много искал, возможно кому-то поможет.

Comment: нет толку от этой писанины. я уже [писал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1239838/2659) такой ответ, можете отредактировать его, с учётом опыта ваших поисков

Comment: @nörbörnën ну я его не нашел) Ситуация другая